# Change the content of a div on click of another link using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a code that changes the data of a div on click of a link, the complete code is displayed [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WoREFEC0B86QBusXb6lE?p=preview)

Part of the code

```
<div class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeView('apple')">Apple content<span class="status-icon"></span></div>
<div class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeView('banana')">Banana content<span class="status-icon"></span></div>
<div class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeView('orange')">Orange Content<span class="status-icon"></span></div>


<div>
    <div ng-show="showApple">{{content}}</div>
    <div ng-show="showBanana">{{content}}</div>
    <div ng-show="showOrange">{{content}}</div>
</div>
```

What i want is that when i click on apple, div gets loaded that has predefined content
e.g

when apple is clicked, this div should get loaded

```
<div> This is apple </div>
```

when banana is clicked, this div should get loaded

```
<div> This is banana</div>
```

when orange is clicked, this div should get loaded

```
<div> This is orange</div>
```

Comment: Your Plunker work just like that, only the text is different. Is that what you want to change?

Comment: check out [shaping up with angular](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js), this is a great interactive tutorial on how the use angular 1.x. The part you should be most interested in is the part on directives.

Comment: @Mary, maybe he is thinking that if that div is clicked, hide that element and instead that show that content on click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, No need to use of more div content for display output

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.content = "";

  $scope.changeView = function(val) {
    $scope.content = val;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeView('apple')">Apple content<span class="status-icon"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeView('banana')">Banana content<span class="status-icon"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeView('orange')">Orange Content<span class="status-icon"></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div ng-show="content">This is {{content}}</div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use

```
 <div>
<div ng-show="showApple">{{content}}</div>
<div ng-show="showBanana">{{content}}</div>
<div ng-show="showOrange">{{content}}</div>
</div>
```

Just do it as follow

```
  <div>{{myContent}}<div>
```

and in code

```
$scope.changeView = function(val){
         switch(val){
           case 'apple' :
         $scope.myContent = 'apple content';
         break;
           case 'bnana' :
         $scope.myContent = 'bana content';
       break;
         }


      }
```

Here is working plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/P0JTkRPS3lnxXHQG1Ysw?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Check out this...

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.changeView=function(frt){
        if (frt==='apple'){
            $scope.fruit=1;
            $scope.content='This is apple';
          }
        else if (frt==='banana'){
            $scope.fruit=2;
            $scope.content='This is banana';
          }
        else if (frt==='orange'){
            $scope.fruit=3;
            $scope.content='This is orange';
          }
      }
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<div class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeView('apple')">Apple content<span class="status-icon"></span></div>
<div class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeView('banana')">Banana content<span class="status-icon"></span></div>
<div class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeView('orange')">Orange Content<span class="status-icon"></span></div>


<div>
    <div ng-show="fruit==1">{{content}}</div>
    <div ng-show="fruit==2">{{content}}</div>
    <div ng-show="fruit==3">{{content}}</div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't complicate  more, It can be simplified more as such:

```js
var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);

app.controller('demoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.fruits = {};
    $scope.fruits.apple = 'Apples are Reds and Greens.';
    $scope.fruits.banana = 'Bananas are Yellows, Greens and Long.';
    $scope.fruits.orange = 'Oranges are Orange and Round.';
    $scope.changeView = function(fruit) {
      $scope.fruits.content = $scope.fruits[fruit];
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='demoApp' ng-controller='demoCtrl'>
  <div class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeView('apple')">Apple content<span class="status-icon"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeView('banana')">Banana content<span class="status-icon"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeView('orange')">Orange Content<span class="status-icon"></span>
  </div>


  <div>
    <div>{{fruits.content}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```